# Is there a way to take the JSON input for an user and then upload the information in a MySQL database as separate items

Tags: python, mysql, json

So I am trying to make a program where the user would enter their information and a min of 5 and a max of 10 restaurant options in JSON format where the separate restaurants would be their own entry in a table.

| UserID | Restaurant Chosen |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | resta, restb, etc |

What I want is the format below but in a MySQL database

| UserID | Restaurant Chosen |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | RestA |
| 1 | Restb |
| 1 | Restc |

I am using python to code the API and Postman for the user to input the information in a json format, which will update the information in a MySQL database. Is what I am asking even possible? I am still learning about programming.

Comment: Yes of course it is. Postman sends json POST to python. Python reads it, loops it and for each element, makes request to db to save it. You should study the parts you don't know. POST, Json, MySQL, related to python.

Comment: How would I write the loop method?

Comment: Check those two, I'm not a Python developer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24119878/115050 https://stackoverflow.com/a/42445385/115050 just think of each step you need and go to learn a python course/tutorial about that specific step