# How to loop through particular element in the payload or JSON

Tags: python, django

I trying to insert all the fields from the payload where values of `QId` and `Answer` changes.
All I did is I tried looping the `QId` and `Answer` but the only one last data is getting inserted. I wanted to insert all value of the `QId` and `Answer`

views.py

```
  cursor = connection.cursor()
   for ran in request.data:

            print('request.data--', ran)
            auditorid =ran.get('AuditorId')
            print('SaveUserResponse auditorid---', auditorid)
            ticketid = ran.get('TicketId')
            qid = ran.get('QId')
            answer = ran.get('Answer')
            sid = '0'
            print('sid--', sid)
            for i in request.data:
               qid = i['QId']
               print('qid--', qid)
               answer = i['Answer']
               print('answer--', answer)
        
            
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_SaveAuditResponse] @auditorid=%s,@ticketid=%s,@qid=%s,@answer=%s,@sid=%s',
                                        (auditorid,ticketid,qid,answer, sid))
        print(qid)
        result_st = cursor.fetchall()
        print('sp_SaveAuditResponse', result_st)
    
        for row in result_st:
                print('sp_SaveAuditResponse', row)
        return Response(row[0])
```

payload:

```
        [{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":42,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":43,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""},  

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":44,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":45,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":46,"Answer":"3","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 
{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":47,"Answer":"5","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":48,"Answer":"5","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":49,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":50,"Answer":"5","SID":"0","Comments":""}]
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42445265/15978450

Comment: My question is how I can save all the day in database.In database it just saving the last data 'QId' and 'Answer' @Damoiskii

Comment: If possible could u pls provide the code thanks in advance

Comment: Oh, I misread the question it seems.

Comment: Have you seen my suggestion in the answer I posted?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically overwriting the `Qid` and `answer` within the second `for loop`.

```
for i in request.data:
     qid = i['QId']
     print('qid--', qid)
     answer = i['Answer']
     print('answer--', answer)
```

Not sure what you were trying to accomplish with that loop, but it's looping over `request.data` again which is actually going to the end of it and assigning `"QId":50, "Answer":"5"` for all the other `answers` and `Qids`. Hence why it is saving only the last `Qid` and `answer` for everything.

This should work for you in this case...

```
for ran in request.data:
     auditorid =ran.get('AuditorId')
     ticketid = ran.get('TicketId')
     qid = ran.get('QId')
     answer = ran.get('Answer')
     sid = '0'

     # Remove the second loop

     cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_SaveAuditResponse] @auditorid=%s,@ticketid=%s,@qid=%s,@answer=%s,@sid=%s',
                                    (auditorid,ticketid,qid,answer, sid))

     # other code below...
```